# Using Docker Django Alpine MSSQL pyobdc

Tags: sql-server, django, docker, pyodbc, alpine-linux

I am trying to run a docker container that can run a Django application with the mssql-django to connect to MSSQL server. However I cannot get the dependency of pyodbc to install correctly. Any help appreciated :)

requirements.txt

```
Django>=4.0.5,<4.1
uWSGI>=2.0.18,<2.1
mssql-django>=1.1.3,<1.2
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN apk add python3 python3-dev gcc g++ linux-headers unixodbc-dev
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install pyodbc --no-binary pyodbc
RUN pip3 install --user -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk update
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
uwsgi --socket :8000 --master --enable-threads --module app.wsgi
```

Error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading pyodbc module: Error loading shared library libodbc.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I have found the following reference and implemented but I am still receiving the error message noted above.
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install

Comment: Aside... how does your Python container even build? Using the posted requirements.txt and Dockerfile it fails to build uWSGI during `pip3 install --user -r /requirements.txt` because it lacks `linux-headers`. The initial apk line should be `RUN apk add g++ linux-headers python3 python3-dev unixodbc-dev`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for replying. Sorry about that, I copied the wrong version of the docker file - edited the question and it builds fine now. However when I type ```docker-compose up``` I run into the error.

Comment: So what does the `DATABASES` dict in your `settings.py` file look like? On non-Windows platforms (such as Docker containers) the `OPTIONS.driver` entry should contain either `FreeTDS` or `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, but you don't seem to be installing either of those drivers in your `Dockerfile`. It's not clear why `pyodbc` is involved, unless you're bypassing `mssql-django` altogether.